# How to select the last row in a table if criteria matches first row

Tags: sql

So I need to select the record for each financial year but only if the first record is in the same financial year. For example:

```
Acc_ref  Fin_year  Amount  Balance  Date
123      2014      -10     80   01.06.2014
123      2014      -10     90   01.05.2014
123      2014      100     100  01.04.2014
321      2014      -10     80   01.04.2014
321      2013      -10     90   01.03.2014
321      2013      100    100   01.02.2014
```

In this instance I'd like to select the acc_ref and balance from the last row where the fin_year matches that of the first row. Therefore I'd only expect to see 123 (acc_ref) and 80 (balance).

select acc_ref, date, balance
from tablename where (acc_ref, date) in (
    select acc_ref, max(date) as date
    from tablename
    group by acc_ref)

But also want to say where fin_year matches min date fin_year

Can this be done?

Comment: WHat db platform?  Please show data in table format.  Impossible to read.

Comment: What is "first row"?  That is not an SQL concept.  Tables represent unordered sets.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think if this is a good question but if you had something like `ID AUTO_INCREMENT` so you could use it as first and last and you can write a SQL query which checks `min(ID)` and shows `max(ID)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, this is a possible solution.

I numbered the rows partitioning by `Acc_ref` and ordering by `Acc_ref, date`, then select the first row if `YEAR(Date)` match `Fin_year`

```
with cteB (Acc_ref, Fin_year, Amount, Balance,  Date, Row)
as
(
    select Acc_ref, Fin_year, Amount, Balance,  Date,
           row_number() over (partition by Acc_ref order by Acc_ref, date) as Row
    from
         your_table
)
select Acc_ref, Fin_year, Amount, Balance, Date, Row
from cteB
where Row = 1 and Fin_year = year(Date);
```